# DataGridVIew row to e-mail

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have DataGridView control where I want cell values from every selected row to be send as an e-mail body text as one string line:

```
        private void buttonReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("hi@greetings.com", "Hello");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("hi1234@gmail.com", "Hi");
        string join;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTest.Rows)
        {
            List<string> email = new List<string>();
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[cbSelect.Name].Value) == true)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (cell.Value != null)
                        {
                            email.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (string items in email.Skip(1).Take(4))
            {
                join = String.Join(", ", items.ToString());
                SendEmail("Hi!", from, to, join);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code, however I am getting 4 mails now because the `SendMail()` is in the foreach loop, if I take it out, the local variable join is not accessible..? how to work around this? I am using the `email.Skip(1).Take(4)` to omit some unnecessary values? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move declaration `List<string> email = new List<string>();` outside foreach. Not sure why you need `Skip(1).Take(4)`

I suggest following code:

```
//declared somewhere above
List<string> CellsForReport = new List<string>{ "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4" }

//code inside buttonReport_Click
List<string> emails = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTest.Rows)
{
  if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[cbSelect.Name].Value) == true)
  {
    //list to collect current row items
    var currentMailItems = new List<string>()
    foreach (var cellName in CellsForReport )
    {
       //this can throw exception if you specified wrong name above
       var cell = row.Cells[cellName];
       if (cell.Value != null)
       {
         currentMailItems.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
       }
    }
    //construct email text from row
    var finalEmailText = string.Join(", ", currentMailItems);
    emails.Add(finalEmailText);
  }
}
//sending 1 email per row
foreach (var email in emails)
{
  SendEmail("Hi!", from, to, email);
}
```

Comment: your suggestion works, thank you for that, as I stated initially, I would like to have only 4 values of the entire row not everything, how could I chose specifically item1, item2, item3 and item4 and send them as the email body?

Comment: @y4wn see my edit: specify real cell names instead of `"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"`

Comment: OK, I have found how to do it `var finalEmailText = string.Join(", ", currentMailItems[1], currentMailItems[2], currentMailItems[3], currentMailItems[4]);`. Thanks a milion!